# Data I pass from ActionFilter via ViewBag not accessible in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass some information from a custom action filter to a view. I use the ViewBag like so but in the view, both the properties `ViewBag.Title` and `ViewBag.Message` evaluate to `null`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    ...

    filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Title = "Session Expired";
    filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Message = "Your session has expired. Please login again.";
    filterContext.Result = 
            new ViewResult 
            { 
              ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Info.cshtml" 
            };
}
```

**In the View**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class = 
             "col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 
              col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 
              col-xs-offset-0">

            <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

            <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the signature of the custom filter attribute and how you apply it to the method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `ViewBag` property on the  [`ViewResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx) where you can set the viewBag items you want to pass to the view. You can set a dynamic object as the value.

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                          {
                             ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Info.cshtml" ,
                             ViewBag= { Message="SS",Title="Hi title"}
                          };
```

Comment: That is strange. I had done that but the members did not show up. Then I wasn't sure what `DynamicDictionary` meant so I ended up passing a reference to the Controller's `ViewDataDictionary` in the `ViewResult.ViewData` member and that worked, too. I was lazy to post the answer. Thanks, though. This might work, too. I should try it again some time.